# Count total cost of price in table col which can be inserted manually

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for help in simple solution for problem. Need a to calculate total price of all existing values in the table. Which added by clicking add product price in bottom of the table.

Simple JavaScript and Jquery

```
$("form#addProduct").submit(function() {
    var product = {};
    var nameInput = $('input[name="name"]').val().trim();
    var priceInput = $('input[name="price"]').val().trim();
    if (nameInput && priceInput ) {
        $(this).serializeArray().map(function(data) {
            product[data.name] = data.value;
        });
        var lastProduct = products[Object.keys(products).sort().pop()];
        product.id = lastProduct.id + 1;

        addProduct(product);
    } else {
        alert("All fields must have a valid value.");
    }
});
```

Full code in the link CodePen
https://codepen.io/ajdos-zhubandyk/pen/pozQzNd

total cost is 120

Comment: it's not a `priceInput` or `nameInput` but the value of it rather. Where in the sample code are you trying to calculate the total price? Please add all relevant code to your question, and not in an outside link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added bit code for your code check with below, just added function to calculate sum go with that code....let me know if you have any doubt on that code.

```js
var products = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Apple",
        price: 70,

    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "Lemon",
        price: 50,

    }
];


$.each(products, function(i, product) {
    appendToProductTable(product);
});

$("form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
calTotal();
function calTotal(){
  var count=0;
  $('#productTable tr').each(function(){
    if(($(this).find('td').length) > 0){
      count = count + parseInt($(this).find('td:last-child').html());
    }
  });       
  $('#Tprice').html(count);
  }
                     
$("form#addProduct").submit(function() {
    var product = {};
    var nameInput = $('input[name="name"]').val().trim();
    var priceInput = $('input[name="price"]').val().trim();
    if (nameInput && priceInput ) {
        $(this).serializeArray().map(function(data) {
            product[data.name] = data.value;
        });
        var lastProduct = products[Object.keys(products).sort().pop()];
        product.id = lastProduct.id + 1;

        addProduct(product);
    } else {
        alert("All fields must have a valid value.");
    }
  
  calTotal();
});

function addProduct(product) {
    products.push(product);
    appendToProductTable(product);
}
function appendToProductTable(product) {
    $("#productTable > tbody:last-child").append(`
        <tr id="product-${product.id}">
            <td class="productData" name="name">${product.name}</td>
            '<td class="productData" name="price">${product.price}</td>            
            
        </tr>     
        <tr></tr>   
    `);

}
```

```css
body, html {
    font-size: 16px;
}
.container{
    max-width: 1170px !important; ;}

.main-title h1{
    margin: 1em 0;
}
.table {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    background-color: transparent;
}
.table-striped tbody tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.05);
}
.table td, .table th {
    padding: .75rem;
    vertical-align: top;
    border-top: 1px solid #dee2e6;
}
.form-control {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(2.25rem + 2px);
    padding: .375rem .75rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #495057;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid #ced4da;
    border-radius: .25rem;
    transition: border-color .15s ease-in-out,box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
}
.btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active, .btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active, .show>.btn-primary.dropdown-toggle {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #0062cc;
    border-color: #005cbf;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" id="cf_styles-css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" media="screen,projection" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="main-title">
                    <h1>Please add the Product</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <form id="addProduct" action="">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input class="form-control" type="number" name="price" min="0" placeholder="Price" required>
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary form-control" type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="main-title">
                    <h1>Products</h1>
                </div>
                <table id="productTable" class="table table-striped">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Price.tg</th>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table id="TotalPrice" class="table table-striped">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Total</td>
                        <td  id="Tprice"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var products = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Apple",
    price: 70,

  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Lemon",
    price: 50,

  }
];
var totalPrice = 0;
TotalPrice();
$.each(products, function(i, product) {
  appendToProductTable(product);
});
$("form").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
$("form#addProduct").submit(function() {
  var product = {};
  var nameInput = $('input[name="name"]').val().trim();
  var priceInput = $('input[name="price"]').val().trim();
  if (nameInput && priceInput) {
    $(this).serializeArray().map(function(data) {
      product[data.name] = data.value;
    });
    var lastProduct = products[Object.keys(products).sort().pop()];
    product.id = lastProduct.id + 1;
    addProduct(product);
  } else {
    alert("All fields must have a valid value.");
  }
});

function addProduct(product) {
  products.push(product);
  TotalPrice();
  appendToProductTable(product);
}

function TotalPrice() {
  for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
    totalPrice = totalPrice + parseInt(products[i].price);
    $("#totalPrice").html(totalPrice);
  }
}

function appendToProductTable(product) {
  $("#productTable > tbody:last-child").append(`
        <tr id="product-${product.id}">
            <td class="productData" name="name">${product.name}</td>
            '<td class="productData" name="price">${product.price}</td>            
        </tr>     
        <tr></tr>   
    `);

}

function calculateSum() {
  var sum = 0;
  //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
  $(".productData").each(function() {
    //add only if the value is number
    if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
      sum += parseFloat(this.value);
    }

  });
  //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
  //$("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(2));
}
calculateSum();
```

```css
body,
html {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1170px !important;
  ;
}

.main-title h1 {
  margin: 1em 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="main-title">
        <h1>Please add the Product</h1>
        <span id='totalPrice'></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <form id="addProduct" action="">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input class="form-control" type="number" name="price" min="0" placeholder="Price" required>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary form-control" type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="main-title">
        <h1>Products</h1>
      </div>
      <table id="productTable" class="table table-striped">
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Price.tg</th>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //iterate through each textboxes and add keyup
  //handler to trigger sum event
  //call initially
  calculateSum();
  $(".txt").each(function() {

    $(this).keyup(function() {
      calculateSum();
    });
  });

});

function calculateSum() {

  var sum = 0;
  //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
  $(".txt").each(function() {

    //add only if the value is number
    if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
      sum += parseFloat(this.value);
    }

  });
  //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
  $("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(2));
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#summation {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #174C68;
}

.txt {
  background-color: #FEFFB0;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="300px" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;background-color:#E8DCFF">
  <tr>
    <td width="40px">1</td>
    <td>Butter</td>
    <td><input class="txt" type="text" name="txt" value='100' /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Cheese</td>
    <td><input class="txt" type="text" name="txt" value='50' /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Eggs</td>
    <td><input class="txt" type="text" name="txt" value='50'/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>Milk</td>
    <td><input class="txt" type="text" name="txt" value='100' /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>Bread</td>
    <td><input class="txt" type="text" name="txt" value='100'/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>Soap</td>
    <td><input class="txt" type="text" name="txt" value='100' /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="summation">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="right">Sum :</td>
    <td align="center"><span id="sum">0</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Note:- Simply you need to call function initially!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the small bit of code that accumulates and shows the total price:

```
$("#getTotal").click(showTotalPrice);

function showTotalPrice() {
    let totalPrice = 0;
    $("#productTable td[name='price']").each(function(index, value) {                
        totalPrice += parseInt($(this).text());
    });
    $("#priceAlert #priceAlertMsg").text("The total price is " + totalPrice);
    $("#priceAlert").show();
}
```

The HTML added just below the table is as follows:

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <button id="getTotal" class="btn btn-primary form-control" type="button">GET TOTAL PRICE</button>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-8">
  <div id="priceAlert" class="alert alert-primary alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
    <div id="priceAlertMsg"></div>
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

The new pen forked from yours is available at https://codepen.io/danypack/pen/qBWQBRZ. Not sure if it's all you need but hope it helps!